# Why groovy does not see some values in dictionary?

Tags: groovy

I started learning groovy, and since I like learning by practice I have written that small app:

```
def height = 1; def commands; def floors; def finished = false

def up = { height < 5 ? height++ : println("Can't go higher!") }
def down = { height > -1 ? height-- : println("Can't go lower!") }
def help = { 
    print "Commands are " 
    commands.each{key, val -> print "'$key' "}
    println() 
}
def printFloors = {
    println "Floors are "
    floors.each{key,val -> println "'$key' -> '$val'"}
    println()
}
def exit = { finished = true }
def prompt = { print floors["$height"] }

commands = [ 'u': up, 
             'up': up,
             'd': down,
             'down': down,
             'help': help,
             '': help,
             'exit': exit,
             'pf': printFloors]

floors = [ "-1": "Basement : " ,
           "0": "Ground : " ,
           "5": "Penthouse : " ]
(1..4).each{floors += ["${it}" : "Floor ${it} : " ] }

bR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))

while(!finished){
    prompt()
    def cmd = bR.readLine()
    def code = commands[cmd]
    if(code != null){
        code()
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except printing on which floor you are (prompt function). It prints if you are in basement, ground floor or penthouse, but doesn't pick up "Floor i: " and prints null instead:/
When I type "pf" to print my floors dictionary, values are there...
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're adding `GString` instances as keys in your map, then searching for them using `String` instances.

The two are not the same (despite having the same appearance -- see *"GStrings aren't Strings"* section [on this page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString))

Try changing:

```
(1..4).each{floors += ["${it}" : "Floor ${it} : " ] }
```

to

```
(1..4).each{floors += [ ("${it}".toString()): "Floor ${it} : " ] }
```

Comment: An equivalent line would be: `(1..4).each{ floors[it as String] = "Floor ${it} : " }`.

Comment: @epidemian I prefer: `floors << (1..4)*.toString().collectEntries { [ (it) : "Floor ${it} : " ] }` ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates Yeah, I would prefer that too. And probably replace `(1..4)*.toString()` with `('1'..'4')` hehe.

Comment: @epidemian I though about `('1'..'4')`, but decided it might cause issues when they get round to finishing the 10th floor ;-)