# Behavior of map.containsKey() - what is the comparison

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to find the existence of a variable number of arguments in a groovy map.  I'm using map.containsKey() and it doesnt seem to be doing a string compare on the key.  Here's the code:

```
println arg_map.keySet()
j = 1
def var = "ARG${j}"
println 'ARG1' == "ARG${j}"
println arg_map.containsKey("ARG1")
println arg_map.containsKey(var)
```

Heres the output:

```
[action, target, ARG1, ARG2]
true
true
false
```

How could the first two be true and the last one be false?  Does containsKey() not interpret variables?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705492/why-groovy-does-not-see-some-values-in-dictionary

Comment: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_gstring_and_string_hashcodes